# Select multiple options in choice field

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to have radio buttons in a choice field that my users can select more than one. Cognito Forms doesn't seem to allow it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To allow your users to select multiple options at once, just open up your Choice field settings and set the field type to Checkboxes.